# Can't able to run nightwatch without using selenium in one terminal

Tags: nightwatch.js

I try to run Nightwatch without using selenium, so I try to run Nightwatch with   Drivers but in this case, I need 2 terminal window. One for starting a driver and 1 for run Nightwatch.

So can some help how to open child process of Driver in Nightwatch to test within one terminal.

Here is my nightwatch.json code:

```
{
  "src_folders": [
    "./tests"
  ],
  "output_folder": "./reports",
  "custom_commands_path": "./custom_commands",
  "custom_assertions_path": "",
  "globals_path": "",
  "live_output": false,
  "parallel_process_delay": 10,
  "disable_colors": false,
  "test_workers": false,

  "test_settings": {
    "default": {
      "webdriver": {
        "launch_url" : "127.0.0.1",
        "start_process": true,
        "server_path": "./node_modules/.bin/chromedriver",
        "port":9515
      },

      "selenium_port": 9515,
      "selenium_host": "localhost",
      "default_path_prefix": "",
      "desiredCapabilities": {
        "browserName": "chrome",
        "loggingPrefs": {
          "driver": "INFO",
          "server": "OFF",
          "browser": "INFO"
        },
        "chromeOptions": {
          "args": [
            "headless",
            "no-sandbox",
            "disable-gpu"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: assuming you are on linux, the shortest and hacky way would be `nohup chromedriver &` and make sure you set the `start_process: false` since you already have it running in background.

Comment: From v1 and onwards nightwatch doesn't need selenium to run the tests.